# How to create popup type textarea for webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in HTML, and i have to create one `textarea` for user input which is looking like the given image below.

Please does anyone have an idea on how to create this type of `textarea`?

I have only basic knowledge of creating simple `textarea`. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fVB6Y/1/)

Play around with `border-left`, `border-right` and `border-top` widths to get suitable notch design

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>

<div id="notch"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea{
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid #7c7870;
    background:#7c7870;
    color:#fff;
      border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   }

#notch{
    position: relative;
    top:-4px;
    left: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 40px solid #7c7870;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; /* ie6 height fix */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0; /* ie6 transparent fix */
    _border-right-color: pink;
    _border-left-color: pink;
    _filter: chroma(color=pink);
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: upvote... btw. you should also add `outline: 0;` to get rid of that ugly square orange outline when you click the box

Comment: and also overflow:hidden or auto for ie

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use jquery ui to create dialog which contains textarea for user input

check this link for demo 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

It's a bummer [`textarea`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea) doesn't support pseudo elements.

Also consider using `box-shadow` to get the full effect.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fsDFU/)