# Altering form fields using CSS content generation

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

The CSS `content` attribute allows me to modify the content of an element. Is it possible to modify an element such that its contents would be posted as part of a form, using pure CSS?

Example of what I want to do:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #sneaky:before {
        content: "Testing, testing!";
    }
</style>
...
<form action="foo.php" action="POST">
    <textarea name="data" id="sneaky"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

According to [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574912/css-content-generation-before-input-elements) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea) on this site, there's no way to use `:before` and `:after` on input elements, but one comment did mention that `textarea` seems to behave specially.

Is there any way to modify form variables (via any element vector) using only CSS?

*Note: This doesn't have to be particularly cross-browser compatible, or reliable. I'm researching how different browsers behave and the tricks that each can be subjected to.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible since `:after` and `:before` create pseudo elements that don't alter input and textarea values in any way (and they're neither seen in the DOM tree)

Comment: I understand that it's not possible for `textarea` using `:after` or `:before`, but are there any ways at all to modify form fields directly from CSS, using any element, selector, attribute, etc?

Comment: no. you cannot alter the dom via css. you cannot change attributes or values via css

Comment: no. it doesn't. CSS is meant to style elements. HTML is meant to give strucuture and meaning and JS is meant to add behaviour. Every layer has its own specific purpose.

Comment: I understand that, it happens to suck for this particular purpose.