# How to get css3 ribbon on both sides of element

Tags: css

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-ribbons/) on how to make a CSS ribbon. However the end result only shows a ribbon on one side of a given element. I'm wondering: given the code in the tutorial, is there a way to get it to appear on both sides? Maybe I'm confused by the meaning of `:before` and `:after`. Do I need to add a `<div>` on either side and target both?

Comment: Showing your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one `:before` and `:after` pseudo element per element, so you need to add another wrapper and style that one with opposing characteristics. I've put one together for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FdEZH/6/), based on the tutorial you referenced.

To understand better pseudo elements, [viewing a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea/3293252#3293252) might be helpful.