# Can I style the resize grabber of textarea?

Tags: css, resize, textarea

My designer just gave me the design with text areas with styled resize grabber. The question is: Can I style it or not ?

Comment: That resize grabber is [way too small on 4K monitors](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884575).

Answer (score 94):

WebKit provides the pseudo-element `::-webkit-resizer` for the resize control it automatically adds to the bottom right of `textarea` elements.

It can be hidden by applying `display: none` or `-webkit-appearance: none`:

```css
::-webkit-resizer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

This displays as follows in Chrome 26 on OS X:

[image: This displays as follows in Chrome 26 on OS X:]

*Note: Adding `display: none` to `::-webkit-resizer` doesn’t actually prevent the user from resizing the textarea, it just hides the control. If you want to disable resizing, set the `resize` CSS property to `none`. This also hides the control and has the added benefit of working in all browsers that support resizing textareas.*

The `::-webkit-resizer` pseudo-element also allows for some basic styling. If you thought the resize control could use significantly more color you could add this:

```css
::-webkit-resizer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px blue;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

This displays as follows in Chrome 26 on OS X:

[image: This displays as follows in Chrome 26 on OS X:]

Comment: Better example: `::-webkit-resizer{ 
 border: 9px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}`

Comment: Hi, Can i place the resizer at the top-right corner?

Comment: Source: http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/

Comment: March 2018: works on current mainstream release of Safari, does NOT work on current mainstream release of Chrome on MacOS

Comment: Does not work on firefox, any solution for that?

Answer (score 26):

Instead of applying CSS to `::-webkit-resizer` (which doesn't appear to be working in Chrome 56 or FireFox 51), you can create a "custom" handle using some markup. I found this example after a google search:

[Custom CSS3 TextArea Resize Handle](http://jsfiddle.net/MM94f/)

Copied markup in case of future dead link:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="pull-tab"></div>
  <textarea placeholder="drag the cyan triangle..."></textarea>
</div>
```

And the CSS from the example - of course, you can apply any style you like :

```
textarea {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrap:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 20px solid black;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    right: -18px;
    bottom: -3px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.pull-tab {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 20px solid cyan;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer {
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent orangered orangered transparent;
}
```

```html
<textarea/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just show a background image?
http://jsfiddle.net/1n0d529p/

```
textarea {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/133/133889.svg)no-repeat rgba(71, 108, 193, 0.52) 99.9% 100%;
  background-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is that the image disappears when the scroll bar is showing up.

Comment: Update your fiddle now, seems like background image used is throwing 404

Answer (score 4):

Styling the resize grabber of textarea using @HorusKol's approach

[Codepen url](https://codepen.io/aadeshkulkarni/pen/eYRRQem)

```css
textarea {
    /* Ignore this part of code - basic textarea formatting */
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width:300px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* Comment below line to resize horizontal + vertical */
    resize:vertical 
    /* Step 1 */
    position: relative;
}
    /* Step 2 */
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
    /* Step 3 - - Sets the 1st line of resize icon */
.wrap:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 2px solid #555;
    width:16px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background:transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    bottom: 14px;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius:25%;
}
    /* Step 4 - Sets the 2nd line of resize icon */
.pull-tab {
    border-top: 2px solid #555;
    width:10px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius:25%;
}
    /* Step 5 - Removes the default resizer grabber icon */
::-webkit-resizer{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="pull-tab"></div>
    <textarea placeholder="Customized resizer grabber...">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do so this way:

```
.textarea-container:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('svg/textarea-resize.svg');
    background-size: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Input Element is not supporting for pseudo code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea

Comment: @Sethuraman it is meant to be used in a parent. e.g. `<div class="textarea-container"><textarea /></div>`

Answer (score -4):

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="72" rows="14"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think the Original Poster asked that how can you *change the style* of the "resize grabber", not how to remove it. Your code just removes the resize feature.