# Is it possible to change the webkit resizer (pulltab) cursor?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have tried adding a custom cursor to my webkit pulltab, but cannot seem to get it working.  Other elements, such as the background color are changable, but the css "cursor" property is not mutable:

```
#sessionbuilder::-webkit-resizer {
  background: #000;
  cursor: help !important;
}
```

Comment: You can't, different browsers handles it differently 

https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Jun/0661.html

Comment: A simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63398119/1405507

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Well, a simple example with webkit is this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
    cursor: wait;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect with a cursor wait.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Yes.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

```
.foo { cursor: crosshair; }

/* use prefixed-value if "zoom-in" isn't supported */
.bar { cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;  cursor: zoom-in; } 

/* standard cursor value as fallback for url() must be provided (doesn't work without) */
.baz { cursor: url(hyper.cur), auto }
```

Comment: Note: cursor: none; not supported until Firefox 3, Safari 5, and Chrome 5. Not at all supported in IE or Opera. Image URL cursors not supported in Opera. The following not supported in IE or Opera: not-allowed, no-drop, vertical-text, all-scroll, col-resize, row-resize

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question I have is specifically with regards to the handle of the ::-webkit-resizer property.  I am not seeing any changes to the cursor using the above CSS styles

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately still not exactly what I'm looking for, though.