# How to make edge of div resizable instead of bottom right corner icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having an issue getting a react component to be horizontally resizable.  When I added the resize property a class in my component like so:

```
.side-menu-container {
    display: 'inline-block';
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow-y: auto
}
```

I am only getting a resizable marker on the bottom right corner of the div like so:

[image]

Instead, I am looking to have the whole right edge of the div be resizable instead of just the bottom right corner.  I know this can be done via javascript (was trying to stay strictly css), but I am not sure now how to go about doing this in my React component.

This is the example of the component where this css class is used:

```
import './app.less';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='main-window-container'>
                <div className='side-menu-container'>
                    <SideMenu />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: but this still resizes the textarea horizontally only right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to style the css3 resize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function)

Comment: @orangespark, it does, just looking for it to be resizable from the right edge instead of the bottom right corner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I style the resize grabber of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea)