# How to change cursor for resizable textarea?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cursor, textarea

I have an HTML element `textarea` with defined CSS rule `{ resize: both }`. In FF when the user mouse over the right bottom corner of `textarea` the cursor changed according to value of property `resize`, but in Chrome cursor doesn't change.

Please open [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_beliakov/4vahwjxe/) in FF and Chrome to check the difference.

Is it a bug of Google Chrome and can I fix it with CSS on my side?

**Update**

I reported bug to Chromium:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942017

**Update 2**

The bug was fixed in Chrome 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rendered by browser itself cant be designed using css

Comment: Is it a bug of Goggle Chrome? What do you think?

Comment: no its not a bug its the default behaviour of chrome.

For ex take a checkbox and open it on Mozilla and chrome you will see different designs when u check it @YuriBeliakov

Comment: I think it is a bug. I reported issue about that to Chromium project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are, or at least were ways in which you could style the resizer and add `cursor: se-resize;` on hover. Check out this post: [Can I style the resize grabber of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea)

It describes how you can use `::-webkit-resizer` to style the resizer:

```css
::-webkit-resizer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px blue;
    outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Unfortunately it stopped working in Chrome and I couldn't anything similar. (I think it still works in Safari).

But fear not, it's not hard to make a custom handle. Actually, I would encourage you to use a custom one as the default one is too small and hard to hit. Especially with touch. There are actually a lot of sites that use custom handles (or at least automatic resizers based which grows based on the content. Works great on touch too!).

Ie. Stackoverflow uses a custom handle (TextAreaResizer):

[GIF of Stackoverflows resize handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNlaK.gif)

There are also lots of libraries for exactly that purpose, just do a Google search, and you'll find something that works for you :)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Unfortunately custom property `-webkit-resizer` does not work any more. I try to apply it to my example, but nothing changes:
https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_beliakov/4vahwjxe/2/

Comment: Yea, it's kind of sucks that it stopped working. It would actually be really useful to at least be able to change its size, hover state etc :)