# Text area not showing resize cursor when hover on corner

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Hi I have small css issue with my text-area inside react component. It is not show resizable cursor when hover on right bottom corner as it should show in normal case. How can I fix this issue please?
Here is my simple sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-moon-oxzpp?file=/src/App.js

Thx for any help

Comment: It shows on my machine, osx Chrome.

Comment: On macOS 10.15.5: shows in Chrome 83 and Firefox 78; does not show in Safari 13.1. See (older) discussion: [How to change cursor for resizable textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163929/how-to-change-cursor-for-resizable-textarea)

Comment: You are right only in safari is not showing