# How to hide (not disable) resize icon in text area?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to find a solution for disabling the resize icon from text area or any thing that has resize property enabled but still couldn't find the solution. Can any one help me with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change cursor for resizable textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163929/how-to-change-cursor-for-resizable-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the resize icon of 'textarea' or any element with resize icon, you can use a simple css property of 'resize: none;'

like this:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Or, you can directly add it to the the html tag

```
<textarea style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

You can also control 'resize' property two more values,

```
resize:vertical; <!-- this makes the element resizable in y-axis -->
resize:horizontal; <!--<!-- this makes the element resizable in x-axis -->-->
```