# Change size of standard resize handle (CSS)?

Tags: css, resize

The resize handle/icon on Chrome for Android (at least on my device) is too small. I can't resize without extreme zoom.

The suggested duplicates addresses the styling and one answer succussefully styles the bottom right corner but the resizing still need me to target the original resizer, which is still too small.

[missing image]

Problem is present in this example as well: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize

Is there a way to change the size of it? On my laptop it's a little bit too intrusive/big instead

I tried using ::-webkit-resizer but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
#r::-webkit-resizer {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The resize Property</h1>

<div id="r">
  <p>Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</p>
  <p>To resize: Click and drag the bottom right corner of this div element.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle where someone sucessfully styled it ---http://jsfiddle.net/MM94f/

Comment: Alternatively, check out this post --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. The jsfiddle doesn't seem to work except as an overlay but I can't resize. ::-webkit-resizer has no effect at all. Pasted the code in my question if there is some problem there?

Comment: The suggested duplicate wants a bigger adjustment. My main issue is to get it functional

Comment: Closest duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea . None of the answers seem to work though...