# Change the comment input pointer to top

Tags: html, css, forms

I want the pointer inside the comment input box which gets located in the middle on focus. I want it to be at the top

```css
div{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;

}

div label{
display: block;
font-family: arial;
}

div input{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="comment">Comment</label>
<input name="comment">
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure that is actually possible. _Why_ do you need to make a single-line text input field this "high" to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `input`, you should use `textarea`. Using an input with a fixed height and width will not change where the cursor starts. It will just extend the input itself. `textarea` is nice because it has a built-in tool where you can resize the text box vertically or horizontally, it will grow based on the amount of text. Instead of defining a preset height and width on it, you can just specify the `rows=""` and `col=""` count in your markup.

```css
div{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;

}

div label{
display: block;
font-family: arial;
}

textarea {  
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="comment">Comment</label>
<textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But can't we remove that adjustment corner and make it fixed

Comment: @ShaikMohammedHuzaifa Yes, just add `textarea { resize: none;}` ~ See edits.

Comment: And one more freaky question can i change the adjustment corner style like rather the double lines a traingle ..................huh huh.

Comment: Have a look here for how to change the style of the resizer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to use textarea instead of a text input for a comment?

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
Are you sure you don't want to use the textarea tag instead?
</textarea>
```

And if you still want it centered you can just add: `text-align: center`