# Styling webkit scrollbar without affecting webkit resizer

Tags: css, sass, webkit

I'm having a hard time styling the scrollbar without affecting my resizer. I managed to style the scrollbar according to specification. The problem is that the resizer changes size and gets an unintended border. When there is no scrollbar, the resizer looks correct. See images below. [See it in Codepen.](https://codepen.io/d-murovec/pen/PoaNPVQ)

[image: Styled scrollbar with messed up resizer]
[image: Correct styles for resizer]

My `.scss` code is as follows.

```css
@mixin scrollbar-styles {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 12px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 99px;
      background-clip: content-box;
      border: 3px solid transparent;
    }
    &.on-dark {
      &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I tried styling with `::-webkit-resizer` but it doesn't work and it's [advised against using it by MDN](https://codepen.io/d-murovec/pen/PoaNPVQ).

Thanks all.

Comment: your codepen link redirecting to **Can I Use**

Comment: My bad. Here's the actual link: https://codepen.io/d-murovec/pen/PoaNPVQ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I style the resize grabber of textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is that there are actually two pseudo elements involved.

`::webkit-resizer`, which is the actual resizer and `::webkit-scrollbar-corner`, which is the corner that appears when you have an scrollbar and a resizer (see [resizer with no scrollbar](https://i.imgur.com/6RYIDPs.png) / [resizer with scrollbar](https://i.imgur.com/F50gIuY.png)).

To get rid of the weird border you just have to style the `::webkit-scrollbar-corner` as well:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```