# Looking for CSS to replace text or a way to target dynamic DIV/Class ids

Tags: html, css

I have a unique situation that might not be solvable with only CSS.  We cant use javascript or any jquery, only CSS.  I am dealing with a web application that I can only edit CSS.  On one of the form pages the application provides I want to change the label of one of the fields.  The page has several form fields.  The problem I am running into is the DIV ids for the forms are dynamically derived.  Every page load changes the DIV id.  I have the HTML shown below.  I am trying to change the text "The Question" to something else.

```
<div class="sm-form-field-overhead" id="yui_3_8_0_1_1378308546310_339">
<label class="sm-label" id="yui_3_8_0_1_1378308546310_340">The Question</label>
<div class="sm-form-field-container" id="yui_3_8_0_1_1378308546310_231">
    <textarea name="question" class="sm-form-field sm-form-field-textarea " id="yui_3_8_0_1_1378308546310_230"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="sm-form-field-description"></div>
```

I can use the :before selector to add text in front of it, but this doesnt hide the other text AND it targets every form field on the page not just the form field I am trying to target

```
.sm-form-field-overhead .sm-label:before {
content: "Message";
```

}

Am I out of luck, or do you think there is a solution?

Here is the complete and total hack I came up with

```
.sm-form-contents .sm-form-field-overhead:nth-child(4) label {
color: #242528;
padding-left: 182px;
}
```

This makes the existing text the same color and shoves it to the right out of the way

```
.sm-contact-pro-form:before {
content: "This is the new text";
position: absolute;
top: 215px;
left: 200px;
}
```

This adds the new text in place.  Like I said, a total hack, but it works for now.  Thanks for the help @Shauna you got me pointed in the right direction.  Its not pretty, but it works for now

Comment: Do you have access to modify the html tags?

Comment: Is there any consistency to the way the ids are generated? IE - do all text area ids start with "yui_3_8_0_1"?

Comment: @itamar No I am afraid not.  This is a subscription service web app and all we get is CSS access.

Comment: @Shauna it appears that yui_3_8_0_1 is consistent.

Comment: is `1378308546310_230` consistent for that field? or `1378308546310_231` for the container?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm tricky one, if you wanted to get a little hacky you could hide the `label` and add the content to the parent `div`, like so:

```
.sm-label{
    display: none;
}
.sm-form-field-overhead:before {
    content: "Message";
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this wont work because .sm-label display none would hide ALL the form fields on the page and add "Message" to every field.  There are several of them.  Thats where I am running into the issue.  I cant figure out a way to target just the one I need because of the dynamic ids

Comment: nth-child? of course that's entering hacky-territory even further

Answer (score 1):

What if you did something like this:

```
.sm-form-field-overhead .sm-label:before {
    content: "Message   ";
}

.sm-form-field-overhead .sm-label { 
    display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Of course, I'm just guessing for the width and height, but that would just hide the text of the label that you don't want to show.

Not very elegant, but might work in a pinch.

Comment: Same problem as above. It would target all the form fields not just the one I need.  I also thought about changing the color of the text to blend it into the background and using the :before selector, but I still run into the problem of targeting only a single form field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can target select CSS like so:

```
div[id^="yui_3_8_0_1xxxxxx"] { ... }
```

with "xxxxx" being whatever constant you can see.

^ basically says: if the id starts with "yui_blahblahblah" target it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the patterns used for the naming of textareas, then you can use some clever CSS to narrow it down to these text areas.

```
label[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"] {
  display: none;
}

textarea[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"]:before {
 content: "New label";
}
```

The `[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"]` is an attribute selector with a "starts with" specification. So it will pick up any label or textarea with an id that starts with that chain.

These are CSS 2.1 selectors and should have good cross-browser support (IE7 is the only exception). However, this does depend on there being naming patterns specific to the text areas themselves and their corresponding labels. The code above, as it is, also depends on that being the only textarea on the page.

You can make the above more specific, but you will start sacrificing browser compatibility.

```
.sm-form-field-container[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"] textarea:first-child:before /* The first matching textarea */

.sm-form-field-container[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"]:last-child textarea:before /* The last matching textarea */

.sm-form-field-container[id^="yui_3_8_0_1"]:nth-child(3) textarea:before /* The third matching textarea, replace the 3 with whatever number to target the desired one. */
```

IE8 doesn't support `:last-child` or `:nth-child`, but IE9 and all relatively up to date versions of everything else should support any of the three. Also, with these, you have to select the container `div` as the `*-child` selectors pick them based on their position within their parent container.

**ETA**: So I was looking at your test page, and I noticed that the textarea is retaining the name (which I didn't see when I first answered the question). Therefore, you can target the textarea itself with `textarea[name="question"]`.

The hard part is still targeting the label. Unfortunately, the textarea is nested in a div, and CSS can't travel up the DOM (so no targeting the div from the textarea). I can't think of any way off hand to get just that one label, since it doesn't have the `for` attribute that it's supposed to have (that'd make your situation too easy). However, you *can* target each form element on their own. It's hacky, but it will get the job done.

```
.sm-label {
  display:none; /* Hide the labels */
}

/* Make new labels using pseudo-elements. */
[name="question"]:before {
  content: "New Label"
}

[name="yourname"]:before {
  content: "Original label"
}

/* Repeat for other form elements. */
```

You can use the attribute selectors on their own, which allows you to target the element based on its attribute, without caring what kind of element it is (so you can change a text input to a textarea and not break the styling).

Like I said, it's hacky, because it's a nuke-the-world, but it will get the job done and won't be too much of a hassle if you're just doing a one-off small contact form. It does have the added bonus of allowing you to change any of the labels if you so choose in the future.

Comment: You may be onto something here, but I cant seem to get it to work.  I even tried the most basic of targeting all textarea with content:  and it didnt seem to work.  Here is a the test page I am working from   http://images.joeywashburn.com/TestPage1/n-TGtvm

Comment: Could we somehow use the textarea name and work backwards.  The text area I am trying to target is the "question"

Comment: @joey - Unfortunately, according to your HTML, there isn't anything linking the textarea to the label (which violates so many standards, I'm amazed that it's a YUI thing, which it appears to be, given the first part of the names). If the labels have their `for` attribute, and it actually matches the textarea, then you can use that for targeting the label, instead of the id. You still have to be able to hit the textarea, but if you can do that, then getting the label might be easier. Unfortunately, too, CSS can't go up the DOM, yet.

Comment: Thanks.  This is as close as I got, but all it does is move "The Question" to the right. `.sm-form-contents .sm-form-field-overhead:nth-child(4) label:before {
    content: "This is the new Message ";
}`

Comment: I am not familiar with `[name]` But in the short research I have done it doesnt look like I can use :before  on a text area  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea  That could be part of my problem.  I cant get any :before to work with textarea and that what the `name` is attached to correct?

Comment: Oh, dangit, I forgot about that. :( Yeah, `name` is attached to the form element. If you can hit one of the div containers, though, you can use them for the pseudo content, though. You need to hide the label to get its text to not show up.