# Inserting some text in textarea using css

Tags: css

In an app i am making i need to show a signature in every message i post using a  textarea.I have tried appending some text using this code with no success.I have tried using the css pseudo-element `after`

This is my textarea  and css code

```
<textarea id="#le_message_compose" placeholder="type your message here"></textarea>

 #le_message_compose:after {
      color: #708090;
      content:'this is my text' !important;
    }
```

but this does not produce the desired effect. How should i have some text displayed inside a textarea?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the answer here: [Can a ::before selector be used with a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286991/can-a-before-selector-be-used-with-a-textarea)

looks like you cant use the :before and :after on elements that don't contain other elements (eg img or textarea)

I also noticed in your html markup that the id is '#le_message_compose' it should probably be just 'le_message_compose', but in any case I think what you are trying is not going to work.

You could use jQuery though:

```
$('#le_message_compose').html('my message in here');
```

Here is a fiddle with the jQuery way : http://jsfiddle.net/5u6pnuvr/

Answer (score 4):

[:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) means child of the selected element, the text of your textarea is not a text node by itself but the value of the textarea node. I think that you should do this with JavaScript instead.

Also, remove the # from the id in your markup, '#' in a CSS selector denotes "id".